# Is 清明节 actually Easter?

Tags: culture

It is Easter in England, and 清明节 in China. Is this a coincidence, or are these festivals actually one and the same moon related ancient celebration?

Comment: It is a coincidence.  清明 has a relatively fixed date every year but Easter's date fluctuates a lot.

Comment: Do you know how whomsoever actually decides when 清明节 should be??

Comment: Good question. Wrong site. It's not really about Chinese language at all, voting to move this...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with Chinese Language. This question should be moved to another SE site, perhaps *history*.

Comment: Since there isn't a community about Chinese Culture, I think this one could serve right for that purpose.

Answer (score 5):

Both festivals revolve around the spring equinox. 清明节 falls 15 days after the spring equinox, whereas Easter falls on the first sunday after the first fullmoon after the spring equinox.

Christianity here just superimposed their own myth (the carpenter on the cross) onto the existing Jewish passover, and the Jews in turn just superimposed their myth (the exodus from Egypt) onto then existing premosaic traditions in West Asia.

清明节 is also a redevelopment of 寒食节, although these festivals are more original than any of the Easter traditions. In Taiwan, 清明节 has unfortunately been politicized to commemorate the death of the nationalist dictator 蒋介石.

Let’s just say that both festivals celebrate the coming of spring, that is the essence of it.

Comment: Easter 复活节 ....

Comment: @S.Rhee you didn't get the question

Comment: Curiously, Easter descends from Pesach/Passover which also has a tradition of not cooking food the usual way: i.e. not leavening the bread because the Jews leaving Egypt had no time to do it.  Is there a traditional story of why 寒食 should e eaten at this Chinese festival?

Comment: 评论应该使用来询问更多的信息或者提出改进建议。必须避免回答问题。

Answer (score 1):

清明節 (Ching Ming) is not Easter. Its origin is 'Cold Food Festival' where people do not cook their food with fire and usually go visit their tombs of their ancestor. Ching Ming, apart from being a festival, is also a traditional solar term (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_term) with the date varies sightly before and after the 5th of April every year.